# How to remove all elements from hash and keep the reference

Tags: javascript

I need to remove everything from a hash/object and keep the reference. 
Here is an example

```
var x = { items: { a: 1, b: 2} }

removeItems(x.items) ;
console.log(x.items.clean) ;

function removeItems(items) {
    var i ;
    for( i in items; i++ ) {
       delete items[i] ;
    }

    items.clean = true ;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a shorter way to achieve this. For example, cleaning an array can be done as follows

```
myArray.length = 0 ;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The `i++` in your code is useless.

Comment: I don't think there is a shortcut for that.

Comment: why do you want to "keep the reference"?

Comment: and what on earth does that even mean?

Comment: @Alnitak I supposed (but I might be wrong) that OP passes a reference to x.items elsewhere and doesn't want to change the object, just empty it. But there probably is a better solution to his problem, like passing an enclosing object.

Comment: ok, but it's dangerous to write code that passes a nested object into a function and assumes that the contents of that object still refer to the same (nested) object afterwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this at the moment, however the ECMAScript committee sees this need and it is in the current specification for the next version of JS.

Here is an alternative solution, using [ECMAScript 6 maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
var x = {}
x.items = new Map();
x.items.set("a",1);
x.items.set("b",2);

//when you want to remove all the items

x.items.clear();
```

[Here is a shim for it](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) so you can use it in current-day browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work:

```
var i ;
for( i in items; i++; ) {
   delete items[i] ;
}
```

It creates a [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) with the init code `i in items` (which btw evaluates to `false` as there is no `"undefined"` key in `items`, but that doesn't matter), and the condition `i++` and no update code. Yet `i++` evaluates to the falsy `NaN`, so your loop will immediately break. And without the second semicolon, it even as a SyntaxError.

Instead, you want a [for-in-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for (var i in items) {
    delete items[i];
}
```

Btw, `items.clean = true;` would create a new property again so the object won't really be "clean" :-)

> I was wondering if there is a shorter way to achieve this. For example, cleaning an array can be done as follows

No. You have to loop all properties and delete them.

Comment: +1 for explaining why OP's code does not work, and the difference between for and for..in loops .

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a shorter way, sorry. Your loop shouldn't have the `i++` though.

```
function removeItems(items) {
  for(var i in items) {
    delete items[i];
  }

  items.clean = true;
}
```

Restructuring your code and just doing `x.items = {}` would be better though.

Comment: When you know where your object comes from, you don't have to use hasOwnProperty.

Comment: @dystroy Potentially, but you never know when something else loaded might augment the Object prototype and not properly make it non-enumerable.

Comment: That's just over zealous. If you use a stupid library, you may have many other random things breaking.

Comment: Also, `delete`ing an inherited property is a no-op.

Comment: and on top of all that, using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` is _definitely_ overkill.

Comment: All valid points. I updated my answer, though I do think that as a beginner, which the OP is, it is very easy to not know what libraries are "stupid" so being cautious doesn't hurt and hopefully makes you more aware of the language's features.